# Why do we pass the value of `this` in the `call()` and apply() functions?

Tags: javascript, oop

In the following example, the value of  `this` is set as `window`.

```
function multiply(n1, n2) {
return n1 * n2;
}

multiply.apply(window, [3, 4]);
```

but in the following example, we didn't mention `window`

```
const mockingbird = {
  title: 'To Kill a Mockingbird',
  describe: function () {
    console.log(`${this.title} is a classic novel`);
  }
};

const pride = {
  title: 'Pride and Prejudice'
};

mockingbird.describe.call(pride);
```

---

**I can't understand the meaning of window and when to use it**

Comment: In the first example, since the `this` really doesn't matter, the dev just put `window` in there because it's the `this` in global context (any other Object would work, even though `null` would be more explicit). In the second example, however, `this` matters. And this time, we want `this` to be the `pride` Object

Comment: If the function doesn't use `this` it really doesn't matter what you pass for a `this` parameter. Mostly I've seen `null` being used. Sometimes an empty object `{}` or just `undefined` but `null` is the most common. I don't think I've actually seen `window`. For why it's passed there...I don't know. Perhaps the code author can say. It's sort of a safe value to use if you're not sure but I don't think it really matters.

Comment: what if I didn't write `window` in the first example? or in other words what if I didn't pass the value of  `this` in the situation where it doesn't matter?

Comment: Again, nothing would happen. The code doesn't use `this`, so the value of it is irrelevant. As I said, mostly in those cases `null` is used.

Comment: @VLAZ The source of the code is from a Udacity example so I can't tell why it's being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window is a global object available when javascript runs in the browsers.

In first code example, since `multiply` function is not using `this`, there is no need to call it with `apply` function and passing `window` object as value of `this`. In non-strict mode, `this` inside functions automatically refers to `window` object.

In the second example, as `describe` function is a method of `mockingbird` object, so to use it with `pride` object, `pride` is passed as a value for `this`

Answer (score 1):

If your functions are not inside an object its outer environment will be set to the `window` and the keyword `this` will refer to it.

In your object `pride` you have a title and inside `mockingbird` you have a function `describe` if you want pride to get use of that describe function you have to bind it to the pride object otherwise the function will not be found so that's where call and apply come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the context where used. So if we call `mokingbird.describe()`, `describe` now has `mokingbird's` context.
But for example if we call describe like,

```
let des = mokingbird.describe;
des();
```

Now, describe is called without context, so it will take global context which is `window`.

And for the first case, we are directly calling the function and using the arguments to perform actions so we do not need `call` or `apply` because they are used only when we want to call a function with different context i.e. using properties of another object in the function.